# How to capture sound from the Line-In device

Tags: actionscript-3, input, audio

I am trying to record the sound of my device connected to Line-In via ActionScript 3.

According to adobe docs ( http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=Working_with_Sound_02.html ), The Microphone class lets your application connect to a microphone or other sound input device on the user's system .

But the Microphone class detects only microphones on my sound card ( Microphone.names array ) , not the "other sound input devices". Maybe there is another way to capture sound from Line-In devices?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Flash is built with security in mind, it won't let you access any hardware except predefined classes like Microphone and Camera (and only after user permission!)
You may have better luck with plugging the device into microphone socket or reroute its signal programmatically, if your soundcard software allows it.